# foreignObject doesn't show up on mobile devices

Tags: html, dom, svg

I have an SVG element which needs to have some html elements in it. I am using foreignObject tag to do this. This works perfectly on normal browsers, but on mobile devices, its not showing the html inside the foreignObject.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="container">
   <svg class="background-svg" width="100" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
         <filter x="" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="10" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.095 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetInner1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" in="shadowOffsetInner1" result="shadowBlurInner1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feComposite in="shadowBlurInner1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" result="shadowInnerInner1"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.647959184   0 0 0 0 0.549016553   0 0 0 0 0.549016553  0 0 0 0.35 0" in="shadowInnerInner1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixInner1"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
               <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
               <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
               <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixInner1"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
         </filter>
      </defs>
      <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
         <g id="Artboard-1" fill="#8B65E4">
            <path d="M187.785156,200 L180,232 L66,232 L58.2148437,200 L187.785156,200 Z" id="Rectangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
            <path d="M349.760339,49.1234675 L375.905579,277.733833 L199.999999,277.733834 L43.9648432,143.710938 L349.760339,49.1234675 Z" id="Triangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
            <path d="M399.8936,96.1889997 L29.4623426,250.140552 L0,36.4302476 L399.8936,96.1889997 Z" id="Triangle-2" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
            <foreignObject x="0%" y="0%" width="80%" height="100%"
               requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
               <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                     <h1>
                        Words appear here on normal browsers but not on mobile devices
                     </h1>
                  </div>
               </body>
            </foreignObject>
         </g>
         <foreignObject x="20%" y="70%" width="80%" height="100%"
            requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
               <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                  <div class="box">
                     <a class="box-item" href="https://website.com/info" target="_blank">link</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </body>
         </foreignObject>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Both my foreign objects do NOT show up on Mobile Devices :( . Is there some other alternate to using ForeignObjects? I need it to insert HTML into my SVG.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your current example isn't even working for me in desktop browsers.

You'll notice no text in the below example.

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="background-svg" width="100" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <filter x="" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="10" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.095 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetInner1"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" in="shadowOffsetInner1" result="shadowBlurInner1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feComposite in="shadowBlurInner1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" result="shadowInnerInner1"></feComposite>
        <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.647959184   0 0 0 0 0.549016553   0 0 0 0 0.549016553  0 0 0 0.35 0" in="shadowInnerInner1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixInner1"></feColorMatrix>
        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
          <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixInner1"></feMergeNode>
        </feMerge>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Artboard-1" fill="#8B65E4">
        <path d="M187.785156,200 L180,232 L66,232 L58.2148437,200 L187.785156,200 Z" id="Rectangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <path d="M349.760339,49.1234675 L375.905579,277.733833 L199.999999,277.733834 L43.9648432,143.710938 L349.760339,49.1234675 Z" id="Triangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <path d="M399.8936,96.1889997 L29.4623426,250.140552 L0,36.4302476 L399.8936,96.1889997 Z" id="Triangle-2" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <foreignObject x="0%" y="0%" width="80%" height="100%" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

          <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <h1>
                        Words appear here on normal browsers but not on mobile devices
                     </h1>
            </div>
          </body>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
      <foreignObject x="20%" y="70%" width="80%" height="100%" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <div class="box">
              <a class="box-item" href="https://website.com/info" target="_blank">link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

However, when I remove the `requiredExtension` attribute from the `foreignObject`, everything loads in the desktop browser. The best part is that it also loads on mobile for me. You'll notice the below example displays the intended text when run.

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="background-svg" width="100" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <filter x="" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="10" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.095 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetInner1"></feOffset>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.5" in="shadowOffsetInner1" result="shadowBlurInner1"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feComposite in="shadowBlurInner1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" result="shadowInnerInner1"></feComposite>
        <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.647959184   0 0 0 0 0.549016553   0 0 0 0 0.549016553  0 0 0 0.35 0" in="shadowInnerInner1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixInner1"></feColorMatrix>
        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
          <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixInner1"></feMergeNode>
        </feMerge>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Artboard-1" fill="#8B65E4">
        <path d="M187.785156,200 L180,232 L66,232 L58.2148437,200 L187.785156,200 Z" id="Rectangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <path d="M349.760339,49.1234675 L375.905579,277.733833 L199.999999,277.733834 L43.9648432,143.710938 L349.760339,49.1234675 Z" id="Triangle-1" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <path d="M399.8936,96.1889997 L29.4623426,250.140552 L0,36.4302476 L399.8936,96.1889997 Z" id="Triangle-2" filter="url(#filter-1)"></path>
        <foreignObject x="0%" y="0%" width="80%" height="100%">

          <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <div>
              <h1>
                        Words appear here on normal browsers but not on mobile devices
                     </h1>
            </div>
          </body>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
      <foreignObject x="20%" y="70%" width="80%" height="100%">

        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <div>
            <div class="box">
              <a class="box-item" href="https://website.com/info" target="_blank">link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot to this example loaded in the iOS simulator with an iPhone 5.

[image: mobile screenshot]